# Cannot send mail from phpmailer on server A + Exim on server B

Tags: php, phpmailer, exim

I have a website hosted on server A. I use Cloudflare services, so I can not send mails to my users from the same server. I have server B for mail sending. Installed Exim and configured it as follows:

```
internet site, mail is sent and received directly using SMTP
Machines to relay mail for: [IP address of the server A]
```

On serevr A I use Phpmailer to send mail:

```
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth   = false;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "";
$mail->Host       = "IP address of server B";
$mail->Port       = 25;
$mail->Username   = "";
$mail->Password   = "";
```

Unfortunately, it doe snot work. Tried to change $mail->SMTPAuth to "true" but it does not help.

```
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've not posted much info to go on, but it's likely that outbound traffic to port 25 is blocked - see if you can `telnet serverb 25` from server A. Normally you can't send out (relay) through port 25 anyway, but use an external authenticated submission host on port 587 instead. You should try reading [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) which covers all kinds of connection issues.